# Up Arrow button action is not writing into Standard output while standard output is redirected

Tags: c#, cmd, postmessage, redirectstandardoutput

I'm creating console application with c# which controls cmd actions from webpage. I start cmd.exe like following

```
                cmdProcess = new Process();
                cmdProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                cmdProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                cmdProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
                cmdProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                cmdProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                cmdProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;`
```

When user from web page press "Up Arrow" button i detect it and send to cmd process with PostMessage() funtion. I can see it takes action it bring previously entered command (like usual cmd application) but this previous command displayed on cmd is not redirected to standard output. That's why i cannot read it from stream and i cannot push it to web client as output.

**My question:** When i send up arrow button to cmd while std output is redirected even it shows previous command on screen why it doesn't write this displayed information to output stream ? or where can i read that stream ?

Comment: Why should it be sent to STDOUT before you actually send it (with ENTER)? (I guess you DON'T want to execute it, so you can read and parse the output of `doskey /history`)

Comment: Yeah you are right. I was thinking about your approach or just keep commands entered by user in some list and show commands as user press up key.  But problem is that I want to support powershell as well so when user press TAB button powershell will auto complete command. Anyway i will have to read autocompleted command for this so if I can solve this problem now with this it will be useful for me and also for powershell.